# Disk corruption problems

Tags: boot

When I log into my user account (Ubuntu 14.04 LTS), I get a blank Ubuntu screen (no menus,just a coloured screen with Ubuntu 14.04 LTS on the left bottom). There are indications that one partition (a FAT partition) on my primary disk (a 64 Gb SSD) has problems.

I can log in through other user accounts and have menus, but what worries me more is the disk problem. I also would like to restore my user account.

I downloaded the Boot-repair-disk, ran some boot repairs, which are seemingly successful, but does not resolve my problem. The last one is at http://paste.ubuntu.com/23856598/

So, I also ran a Boot Info scan. It's information listing is at http://paste.ubuntu.com/23856477/

Please help!

Comment: What makes you believe that there's a problem with the FAT partition? If you log into other accounts, it would probably have a problem there too (assuming that you were mounting the partition in /etc/fstab). If you have Windows, you could boot Windows and do a `chkdsk /f d:` changing the "d" to the appropriate drive letter.

Comment: In my desperation, I took the 16.04LTS installation disk and wanted to upgrade from that source. However, when I come to the point just before the upgrade, it warns that it can only do a clean install due to a problem with the partition. I do not have Windows running on that machine.

However, today I again ran the Boot-repair utility, and now nothing works. I think I will have to simply do the new install.

Comment: Boot the Ubuntu Live DVD, start `gparted`, and figure out which partition is your Ubuntu partition, then open a `terminal` and type `sudo fsck -f /dev/sdaX`, replacing the X with the number of your Ubuntu partition. This will do a file system check/repair.

Comment: I did this, and it ran through, but without success. I still come to the grub menu, and when I leave it to take the Ubuntu option, I just get an Ubuntu coloured blank screen. I then ran Advanced Options and Recovery Mode. It went on for a short while and then ground to a halt. But, here are some important information that it gives:
1. mounting /dev on /toot/dev failed: no such file or directory

Comment: 2. mounting /sys on /root/sys failed: no such file or directory
3. mounting /proc on /root/proc failed: no such file or directory
4 Target filesystem doesn't have requested /sbin/init
5. No init found. Try passing init=bootarg

Comment: re: "I did this, and it ran through, but without success." Please give me more detail.